# Python3 + Digital Ocean: No module named 'torch'

Tags: python, pip, torch

I am trying to install torch on a Digital Ocean Ubuntu droplet. I am following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-pytorch):

```
mkdir ~/pytorch
mkdir ~/pytorch/assets
cd ~/pytorch
python3 -m venv pytorch
source pytorch/bin/activate
```

Running the command `pip install torch==1.7.1+cpu torchvision==0.8.2+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html` results in the error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.7.1+cpu (from versions: 1.13.0, 1.13.0+cpu, 1.13.0+cu116, 1.13.0+cu117, 1.13.0+cu117.with.pypi.cudnn, 1.13.1, 1.13.1+cpu, 1.13.1+cu116, 1.13.1+cu117, 1.13.1+cu117.with.pypi.cudnn, 2.0.0, 2.0.0+cpu, 2.0.0+cpu.cxx11.abi, 2.0.0+cu117, 2.0.0+cu117.with.pypi.cudnn, 2.0.0+cu118, 2.0.1, 2.0.1+cpu, 2.0.1+cpu.cxx11.abi, 2.0.1+cu117, 2.0.1+cu117.with.pypi.cudnn, 2.0.1+cu118, 2.0.1+rocm5.3, 2.0.1+rocm5.4.2, 2.1.0, 2.1.0+cpu, 2.1.0+cpu.cxx11.abi, 2.1.0+cu118, 2.1.0+cu121, 2.1.0+cu121.with.pypi.cudnn, 2.1.0+rocm5.5, 2.1.0+rocm5.6)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.7.1+cpu
```

So I have tried both the following instead (which seem to run successfully):

```
pip3 install torch torchvision
pip install torch torchvision
```

However when I try importing torch in python, I get an error:

```
>>> import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

Why can't python find torch? What do I need to do to ensure I can use the module?

Comment: check the python version in both of the environment

Comment: What is your platform : `CUDA 11.8`, `CUDA 12.1` or `CPU`?

Comment: I'm trying to run it on CPU

Comment: Python 3.11.6 in both environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following command to install PyTorch for CPU in Linux (from the ['get started' docs](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/))

```bash
source pytorch/bin/activate
python -m pip install torch torchvision --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu
python -c 'import torch'  # check that torch is found
```

It is possible that `pip` is pointing to a different `python` distribution, which might explain why torch is not found by python.

Note the use of `python -m pip` instead of `pip`. That uses the pip that is associated with `python`. Using a naked `pip` might point to a differnet python installation.